# Software library for Hidden Markov Modeling of a large text database

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, information-retrieval

Given

- we have a large database of texts (e.g. product descriptions)
- and we want to extract multiple types of information (e.g. brand, release date, features, price, etc.)

what's a good library to use?

I have found many general purpose HMM libraries (such as HMM in R, GHMM, Jahmm, etc.) but I wonder which is the best suited for our problem (i.e. input is text and there are many types of "targets").

Thanks.